# How to check if all of variadic template arguments have special function?

Tags: c++, function, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

**Explanation:**

Checking if a special operator exist in a template parameter is easy (with help of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-c-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence/3627243#3627243)).

The following code checks if `char operator[]` exists in `Type` or not:

```
template <class Type>
class HasStringOperator
{
    template <typename T, T> struct TypeCheck;

    typedef char Yes;
    typedef long No;
    template <typename T> struct operator_{
        typedef char (T::*fptr)(int);
    };

    template <typename T> static Yes HasOperator(TypeCheck< typename operator_<T>::fptr, &T::operator[] >*);
    template <typename T> static No  HasOperator(...);

public:
    static bool const value = (sizeof(HasOperator<Type>(0)) == sizeof(Yes));
};
```

[ideone](https://ideone.com/GLxFq9)

**Problem:**

Now I want to check if all of my variadic template parameters have that operator. I can't figure out how to send them one by one to `HasStringOperator` and check the whole result.

```
template < class... Word>
class Sentence
{
    static_assert(Do all of Words have 'char operator[]'?);
};
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just apply it to every type and compare it to an array of `true`s.

```
template <bool... b>
struct BoolArray {};

template <class... TS>
struct DenyType : true_type {};

template <class... World>
class Sentence {
    static_assert(is_same<
        BoolArray<(HasStringOperator<World>::value)...>,
        BoolArray<(DenyType<World>::value)...>
    >::value, "WUT");
};
```

Answer (score 4):

I want simplify   @polkovnikov.ph's answer:

```
template< bool ... b> struct BoolArray{};
template< bool ... b> struct ctx_all_of: std::is_same< BoolArray<b...>, BoolArray<(b,true)...> >{};


template< class... World>
struct Sentence: ctx_all_of< HasStringOperator<World>::value ... >{};
```

Comment: You should replace `(b,true)` with `(b||true)` as the former leads to warnings about `left operand of comma operator has no effect` on GCC.